# what is the purpose of a hash map (object() and map() in javascript) if my data is already in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

If I have an array of data:

`var foo = ["james", "tony", "michael"]` ,

how is iterating through that and putting it in a Map() or Object() more efficient?  I guess i'm trying to find an example where/how putting data in a hash table is used vs how it's used in an array.

Comment: That completely depends on how you structure the object.

Comment: How is an array related to `Map`/`Object`? Do you mean `Set`?

Comment: In JavaScript you can look at an array as an object with keys set by default to numbers/index.
Use array when you want index based access and map/object when you need key based access.

Comment: @str more so why/how is it more efficient if I had `var foo = { 0:"james, 1:"tony", 2:"michael"}` . vs  `var foo = ["james", "tony", "michael"]` ?  like how can that data structure (an object() or map()) be used more efficiently ?  I'm sure it's a basic data structure question but I just don't understand what i can do with that that i cannot do with an array.

Comment: @BogdanVolosincu thanks Bodgan.  I've been told over and over at school that Objects are just more efficient time wise, but I don't get why or how.  Isn't it the same basic concept, except like you mentioned, we use keys for objects and indices for arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Suppose you have an array of persons:

```
var persons = [{id: 3, name: "Michael"}, {id: 2, name: "Tony"}, {id: 1, name: "James"}];
```

In this case, if you want to get a person by id from this array, you do:

```
var id = 1;
var person = persons.find(p => p.id === id);
```

array.find loop through your array to find the person which id is equal to 1, and that's is the problem (performance)

By using an object to store your data like below:

```
var persons = {
   1: {id: 1, name: "James"},
   2: {id: 2, name: "Tony"},
   3: {id: 3, name: "Michael"}
}
```

It becomes efficient to get a person by it's id:

```
var id = 2;
var person = persons[id];
```

It's short and efficient (no loop)

Comment: but wouldn't calling on the array `person[id + 1]` yield that same result as what you did with the object?

Comment: No, it doesn't provide the same result in case the array is not sorted by id or if ids are not consecutive

Comment: Its better to show example using some string values like 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde' etc instead of int keys. Your example may create confusion who are new to js and don't have deep understanding of objects and arrays. Because in this case we can get same result in same efficient way with persons[id-1] where persons is array.

Comment: @vikram ah ok, so if i was using integer keys for my Object, it'd have yielded the same result with the same efficiency?

Comment: @LionelYang yes, for your in case of integer case you get exactly same result. see this example for your understanding

Comment: @LionelYang here is the link you can check the bench marks of fetching data with key in object or index in array both are almost same see this example for your understanding https://codepen.io/vikrambilla/pen/zWaVbw?editors=1112